# Always having a daemon thread in Python

Tags: python, multithreading, python-multithreading

Let's say I have a simple function that needs to make a GET request, like:

```
def the_function(url):
    requests.get(url)
    # further processing logic
```

I need to have this run at all times in my Django app, so like a background task that would be working in a separate thread. How can I make sure I always have that one daemon thread (the only one besides the main thread) running? The only thing I could think of is to have a recursive loop, but that would eventually start consuming way more resources that it should.

Comment: You can look into something like [django-background-tasks](https://django-background-tasks.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

Comment: @GrajdeanuAlex, I don't want to use any external tools here like Redis, RabbitMQ, python-rq, DBT, celery...